# Next 13 — client and async server component combined: 'Promise<Element>' is not a valid JSX element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I was playing with the experimental Next 13 `app` directory.

As per the [documents](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#importing-server-components-into-client-components), a client component can accept a server component, as long as it is as a `children` prop.

It works, however I do get a type error

> 'ServerPage' cannot be used as a JSX component.   Its return type
> 'Promise' is not a valid JSX element.
> Type 'Promise' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key

```
import ClientPage from './clientPage';
import ServerPage from './serverPage';

// app/page.tsx
export default function Home() {
  // logs in the server
  console.log('rendering home page');

  return (
    <>
      <ClientPage>
        <ServerPage /> // type error here
      </ClientPage>
    </>
  );
}
```

the **serverPage.tsx** component

```
const fetchSomeData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto');

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(response.statusText);
  }

  return response.json();
};

export default async function ServerPage() {
  const data = await fetchSomeData();
  // this logs in the server
  console.log(data);

  return (
    <>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        Im a server component
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

the **clientPage.tsx** component

```
'use client';

export default function ClientPage({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  // this logs in the client
  console.log('rendering client page');
  return (
    <>
      {children}
    </>
  );
}
```

I suppose that this has to do with the children type in the `clientPage` component, but I'm not sure how this should be typed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way around this at the moment is to use the `:any` type definition on the async server components. `Next.js 13` outlined this in their [Typescript documentation](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/configuring/typescript).

> Warning: You can use async/await in layouts and pages, which are Server Components. Using async/await inside other components, with TypeScript, can cause errors from the response type from JSX. You might see the error 'Promise' is not a valid JSX element. We are tracking [this issue here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42292).

Comment: that's ugly, but I think expected since this is all experimental

Answer (score 5):

## Async Server Component TypeScript Error

To use an async Server Component with TypeScript, ensure you are using TypeScript 5.1.3 or higher and @types/react 18.2.8 or higher.

If you are using an older version of TypeScript, you may see a 'Promise' is not a valid JSX element type error. Updating to the latest version of TypeScript and @types/react should resolve this issue.

next.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: { serverActions: true },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;

``
```

Comment: just increase versions is enough, edit next.config.js is not required for me.

Comment: But React doesn't support this yet. I am on latest React 18.2.0 version and it throws the same error at runtime.

Comment: Thank god! After 2 days of looking for a solution. Upgrading `@types/react` did it. Don't get why it is so hard to find such an example and Next.js' team not highlighting it more. For reference in the Next.js documentation: [Fetching Data on the Server with fetch](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#fetching-data-on-the-server-with-fetch) in the `Good to know` rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. Next.js team has been working on it. You could also use eslint comment

```
  <ClientPage>
    // @ts-expect-error Server Component
    <ServerPage /> // type error here
  </ClientPage>
```