# Cannot use vscode workspace path for next js 13 project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js

I am currently getting a TypeScript error shown in the thread below despite having the most recent TypeScript and react types versions on my project (TypeScript 5.2.2 and `@types/react 18.2.21`:

[Next 13 — client and async server component combined: 'Promise<Element>' is not a valid JSX element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75497449/next-13-client-and-async-server-component-combined-promiseelement-is-not)

I then saw the below thread so I tried using a TypeScript workspace version since my VS code version is on 4.5.4

[async server component throwing error with new typescript version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76775081/async-server-component-throwing-error-with-new-typescript-version)

I am now getting this error. I have checked to make sure the file is in my project and reloaded my vscode window:

`/Users/abuhelos/Desktop/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js` doesn't point to a valid tsserver install. Falling back to bundled TypeScript version.

I also tried making a `.vscode` file for my project:

[How to use TypeScript version defined in settings.json by default in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49949148/how-to-use-typescript-version-defined-in-settings-json-by-default-in-vscode)

Here is my `settings.json` file:

```json
{
    "workbench.editor.closeOnFileDelete": true,
    "typescript.enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk": true,
    "typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```

Comment: `.vscode` is a folder. Please post your full `settings.json`

Comment: Just added settings.json. Will try removing node_modules/npm install in a bit will let you know how that works out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are mixing package mangers (like `yarn` and `pnpm`).

Remove the `node_modules` and try to reinstall everything using only `npm install` and then try again.

Comment: This did not work. I deleted my `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` file, used `npm install`, and then refreshed my vscode window, getting the same error.